# Runtime "could not find implicit value for parameter" error when using Scala's builder idiom

Tags: scala, builder, implicit

I am writing a Scala class that implements a 2-dimensional matrix of arbitrary objects. I need the class to be more specialized than nested pair of `IndexedSeq` objects, but extending a collections class is overkill, so I'm writing my own. In order to return the correct type from methods in my matrix class, I am using the implicit builder idiom, but at runtime I get a "could not find implicit value for parameter" error which I don't understand.

A stripped-down version of my matrix class looks like this.

```
trait MatrixBuilder[V, M <: Matrix[V]] {
  def apply(values: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[V]]): M
}

abstract class Matrix[V](values: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[V]]) extends Function2[Int, Int, V] {

  def apply(row: Int, col: Int): V = values(row)(col)

  def set[M <: Matrix[V]](row: Int, col: Int, value: V)(implicit builder: MatrixBuilder[V, M]): M =
    builder(values.updated(row, values(row).updated(col, value)))
}

case class IntMatrix(values: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Int]]) extends Matrix[Int](values)

object IntMatrix {
  def apply(n: Int) = new IntMatrix(IndexedSeq.fill(n, n)(0))

  implicit object IntMatrixBuilder extends MatrixBuilder[Int, IntMatrix] {
    def apply(values: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Int]]) = IntMatrix(values)
  }
}
```

I want the `set` function to set the specified cell then return a new matrix of the correct type. So I expect `IntMatrix(2).set(0,0,5)` to return an `IntMatrix` object with zeros in all cells except (0,0), where it should have a 5. Instead I get the following error at runtime.

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter builder: MatrixBuilder[Int,M]
    IntMatrix(2).set(0,0,5)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

As [pedrofurla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480674/pedrofurla) notes below, the code does work in the REPL if you first run the line `import IntMatrix._`. And looking at the [collections documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html), there appear to be similar import statements in source code using builders. I tried adding one to my `IntMatrix` class.

```
case class IntMatrix(values: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Int]]) extends Matrix[Int](values) {
    import IntMatrix._
}
```

But this has no effect. (In fact my IDE IntelliJ flags this as an unused import statement.)

For comparison I copied over the RNA sequence example from the collections documentation linked above verbatim. There the `import RNA._` line is not marked as superfluous and all operations return the correct type. If the answer is that I need to add an `import IntMatrix._`, I can't figure out where to put it.

Comment: You might want to include a definition of your Solution class, so someone can paste the code somewhere, make the `IntMatrix(2).set(0,0,5)` call, and reproduce the issue.  I'm tempted to think that since IntMatrix isn't parameterized it might not be seen as a subclass of Matrix[Int], and so doesn't fit the definition of your type M required for the implicit builder?  I'm not really sure about that though.  This was at runtime not compile time?

Comment: `Solution` was a typo. It should have been `IntMatrix`. I fixed this. This is a runtime error. `IntMatrix` extends `Matrix[Int]` which I think should meet the type signature of the builder.

Comment: It should be in scope during the call of `set`. Add this explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little code worked here:

```
scala> import IntMatrix._
import IntMatrix._

scala> IntMatrix(2).set(0,0,5)
res1: Mat.IntMatrix = <function2>
```

Implicit parameters are filled by compiler in the call site, so they have to be available in the scope `set` is being invoked.

Comment: Yep. That works for me too, but I get my error when I don't first enter `import IntMatrix._`. Now the question is, how do I change the source code to get this effect?

Comment: The `import IntMatrix._` line appears to be a step in the right direction. I've updated the original question to reflect your comment.

Comment: I also removed the superfluous `new` keyword from the `IntMatrix` builder.